# Query multiple polygons with PostGIS and Graphql

Tags: graphql, postgis, hasura

I am making a search page for geographic locations using Hasura for generating the Graphql, and PostGIS.

I can successfully make a query with a polygon where I get all locations that are within that area. Now I would like to expand this query to include several polygons (so that the user can select multiple city areas in a filter for example), but I cannot figure out how to include more than one polygon at a time.

This is my current query that works. I send in a polygon and get all locations that have their geoData (geoJSON point) within the polygon returned.

```
query GetLocationsByGeometry($_st_within: geometry = "") {
  locations(where: {geoData: {_st_within: $_st_within}}) {
    id
    name
    address
  }
}
```

with the query variables as follows:

```
{"_st_within": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              18.062185142795528,
              59.32774510280629
            ],
            [
              18.062185142795528,
              59.320788019587354
            ],
            [
              18.078984557106565,
              59.320788019587354
            ],
            [
              18.078984557106565,
              59.32774510280629
            ],
            [
              18.062185142795528,
              59.32774510280629
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
}
```

How can I expand this to look at several polygons in the same query?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the _or operator in graphql:

```js
query GetLocationsByGeometry($_st_within: geometry = "", $_st_within1: geometry = "") @cached {
  locations(where: {_or: [{geoData: {_st_within: $_st_within}}, {geoData: {_st_within: $_st_within1}}]}) {
    id
    name
    address
  }
}
```